# Use the hex code value from each custom field to change the category links foreach post in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use the value for each custom field added on the edit category screen to style the category links foreach post in a loop.

This works but it only uses the value for the first custom field key when a post is assigned more than 1 category.

```
$cats = get_the_category();

$list = get_the_category_list( trim( $atts['sep'] ) . ' ' );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {

foreach ( $cats as $term ) {

$selector = 'category_' . $term->term_id;

$color    = get_field( 'cat_color', $selector );

$cats     = str_replace( '<a', "<a style='color:$color'", $list );

    }

}
```

This is the result showing it doesn't work on posts linked to more than 1 category :

[image]

This is what it should do :

[image]

When i echo $color, it does output both hex codes but doesn't change them when using $cats so i assume the problem is in this line :

```
str_replace( '<a', "<a style='color:$color'", $list );
```

Comment: You're currently overwriting the same variables on each iteration of your foreach loop so in the end, they will only contain the values from the last iteration. Either output the link inside the loop, or store them in an array and iterate through that when outputting the links.

Comment: Even when i remove the foreach loop i still get the same result. I guess i need to use the foreach loop in a different way or with a different variable?

Comment: You misunderstood. I've added an answer with the two suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're currently overwriting the variable on every iteration of your loop. This means that after the loop, it will only contain the data from the last iteration.

You need to either output the data directly inside the loop, or add them to an array inside the loop which you then iterate when you should output the data.

#### Alternative 1 - Output inside the loop

This will echo the links immediately inside the loop

```
foreach ( $cats as $term ) {
    $selector = 'category_' . $term->term_id;
    $color    = get_field( 'cat_color', $selector );
    // Output it directly
    echo str_replace( '<a', "<a style='color:$color'", $list );
}
```

#### Alternative 2 - Store it in an array

This will store the links in an array which you can use to output them later in your script

```
// Initialize the array
// Let's use a new variable instead of reusing $cats, which is the initial array
$links = [];

foreach ( $cats as $term ) {
    $selector = 'category_' . $term->term_id;
    $color    = get_field( 'cat_color', $selector );
    // Add the string to the array
    $links[] = str_replace( '<a', "<a style='color:$color'", $list );
}
```

And then you can output the links:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its close but i need to return the value as $cats as i already have the output coded as its wrapped in a filter. Its outputs twice using your code.

Comment: @Brad - So go with alternative 2 and just do `return $links;` after the loop instead of the second `foreach`. You obviously need to adapt the answer to fit your, for us completely unknown, code.